# How to name an SQLite database so it doesn't have the default name of main?

Tags: database, sqlite

How can I name an SQLite database so it doesn't have the default name of `main`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. "main" is simply the name which SQLite always uses for the primary database that you have open. (If necessary, you can add extra databases using `ATTACH`, though.)

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

Comment: The ".databases" command shows a list of all databases open in the current connection. There will always be at least 2. The first one is "main", the original database opened.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think so.

The `main` database has a special meaning.
You can attach other databases with other names.

From http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

> The ".databases" command shows a list of all databases open in the current connection.  There will always be at least 2. The first one is "main", the original database opened. The second is "temp", the database used for temporary tables. There may be additional databases listed for databases attached using the ATTACH statement. The first output column is the name the database is attached with, and the second column is the filename of the external file.

Comment: I cannot until X minutes passed and I will be marking duskwuff's as the only criteria I have is time and he was a mere 2 minutes faster. But I am still grateful.