# How to change database name in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have to simply change name of database, but it seems the `ALTER DATABASE` command is not valid in SQLite.

My scenario is that I have a SQLite encrypted database, and now I want to rename it. After manually renaming the db file, encryption is not working. So I tried to change the database's name using command. It looks like problem is due to encryption.

Comment: Why do you need it? can you share the scenorio?

Comment: @YaqubAhmad, if you're building queries in a multi-database environment, you need to explicitly specify the name. Copying those queries to a single-database environment would require removing the database name, unless you could give the single-database a name matching the one the queries are using.

Comment: For `main` specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313190/can-i-name-sqlite-databases

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no database name in SQLite because there's only one database per file. Maybe what you want to do is rename the SQLite file instead.

Comment: I tried that but the original file is encrypted and when I change filename same password is not working for it.

Comment: This is not true, sqlite allow you `attach` another database. And .databases would list them.

Comment: The file name has nothing to do with the database name in SQLite. By default there are two databases main and temp.

Answer (score 15):

Each sqlite file contains one and only one database. This database bears no name. For what I can remember, the first opened  database has a 'virtual' name `main` for when you want to refer to it say when you attach supplementary databases. You get to choose the 'virtual' name of databases you attach.

```
[someone@somewhere tmp]$ sqlite3 bla.db
SQLite version 3.7.11 2012-03-20 11:35:50
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /tmp/bla.db                                  
sqlite> attach database 'example.db' as another_db;
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /tmp/bla.db                                  
2    another_db       /tmp/example.db
```

Otherwise Laurent is correct that you can rename the database file if that is what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Sqlite3 there is the **.backup** command.

If the database is not big this could be a solution:

```
S:\>sqlite3 encrypted.db
SQLite version 3.7.9 2011-11-01 00:52:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .backup new.db
sqlite> .q
```

then

```
S:\>sqlite3 new.db
SQLite version 3.7.9 2011-11-01 00:52:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```