# How to Upgrade Sqlite DataBase to Next Version in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to update my android application on the market to next version. In that I need to change the sqlite database name without losing the existing data.

Comment: why you need to change database name? you can create new table and transfer your data to it ?

Comment: I created duplicate copy of another project into my project and I submitted it into app store also,But I need change the DB name related to my project.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10846002/1332870

Comment: (Ersin Gülbahar) You are right. It's not possible to rename a sql table directly.But I try to copy it creating a new and deleting the old one. thanks.

Comment: yes it is possible and you can do it ?